# How to run a swing input dialog in EDT and get return value?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Okay I've the following problem, I wrote a simple GUI client for a chat application and I need to ask the user for it's username with help of a `JOptionPane` InputDialog. Now, this dialog should appears when the server sends a specific notification. So the dialog will start from a second thread, **not** from the EDT thread.

I tried to start the dialog in the EDT thread now by executing...

```
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
{
    @Override public void run()
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a username:",
            "Username selection", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
});
```

Header of my function which contains the given code and should **return** the user input:

```
public String showNameInputDialog()
```

My problem is, that I can't receive the user input (Can't use a local variable)  from the dialog because I started it in a inner class. So my question is, is there an option to receive the user input and run the dialog still in the EDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a container variable to capture the result:

```
final String[] resultContainer = new String[1];
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
{
    @Override public void run()
    {
        resultContainer[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose a username:",
            "Username selection", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
});
String result = resultContainer[0];
// ... do something with result.
```